# how to access android reference guide from eclipse code view?

Tags: android, eclipse

In Visual Studio , in your code , if you double click on a class then press F1, it opens msdn in your browser and shows the page that describe the class.

can we do that on eclipse to shows android dev site?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this. Point to the element and press Shift + F2 (Open  External Java Doc)

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what i was looking for. I also edited Settings=> General => Web Browser to set external Web browser. So the doc appears in fullscreen thanks to firefox.

Comment: Great! I don't know that. Then You can mark this answer as correct.
And in my eclipse. Its Shows me => Window=> Preference=> General=> Web Browser=> Use External Web Browser(radioButton) => Firefox.

Comment: it's done, sorry for the delai, didn't know how to do that. Thanks again.